# C program calling a string to int function, I am unable to convert the input

Tags: c, string, int, program-entry-point

I would like to convert a string to an `int` and calling the function from `main`. Where the first character is a letter declaring the base of the number and the rest of the characters in the string are the number. I am able to get the function to work separately, but when using the `main` function to call it will not print out the correct values.

Example of  user input using binary:

```
b1000
b1010
```

result should be:

```
b
b
1000
1010
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int str_to_int(inputbase) {
    char num1[50];
    num1[50] = inputbase;

    char numcpy1[sizeof(num1) - 1];

    int  i, len1;
    int result1 = 0;

    //printf("String: ");
    //gets(num1);

    //Access first character for base
    printf("%c \n", num1[0]);

    //Remove first character for number1 and number 2
    if (strlen(num1) > 0) {
        strcpy(numcpy1, &(num1[1]));
    } else {
        strcpy(numcpy1, num1);
    }
    len1 = strlen(numcpy1);

    //Turn remaining string characters into an int
    for (i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
        result1 = result1 * 10 + ( numcpy1[i] - '0' );
    }

    printf("%d \n", result1);
    return result1;
} 

int main() {
    char *number1[50], *number2[50];
    int one, two;

    printf("\nAsk numbers: \n");

    gets(number1);
    gets(number2);

    one = str_to_int(number1);
    two = str_to_int(number2);

    printf("\nVerifying...\n");
    printf("%d\n", one);
    printf("%d\n", two);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `int str_to_int(inputbase)` compile on your machine?  What compiler are you using?

Comment: This looks very much like a homework question to me.

Comment: I am using a gcc compiler. The function int str_to_int(inputbase) does compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your code cannot be compiled because some errors.

The first one is in the line

```
 int str_to_int(inputbase)
```

where `inputbase` are defined without type.

If this changed to

```
 int str_to_int(char * inputbase)
```

the next point for improvement is in line

```
 num1[50] = inputbase;
```

assignement like that has set of errors:

1. `num1[50]` means access to 51th item, but there is only 50 items indexed from 0 to 49
2. statement `num1[0] = inputbase;` (as well as with any other correct index) is wrong because of difference in types: `num1[0]` is `char`, but `inputbase` is pointer
3. `num1 = inputbase;` will be also wrong (for copying string `=` cannot be used in C, so consider making loop or using standard library function `strncpy`)

And since this is only the beginning of problems, I suggest starting from decimal input using some standard function for conversion `char*` string to `int` (e.g. `atoi`, or `sscanf`), then after you check the program and find it correct if it is required you can avoid using standard conversion and write your own `str_to_int`

Comment: Do not advocate the use of `strncpy()`, it is never the right tool, especially for beginners. Also discourage the use of `gets()`.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype for your function `str_to_int()` should specify the type of `intputbase`. You are passing a string and there is no reason for `str_to_int` to modify this string, so the type should be `const char *inputbase`.

Furthermore, you do not need a local copy for the string, just access the first character to determine the base and parse the remaining digits accordingly:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int str_to_int(const char *inputbase) {
    const char *p = inputbase;
    int base = 10;    // default to decimal

    if (*p == 'b') {  // binary
        p++;
        base = 2;
    } else
    if (*p == 'o') {  // octal
        p++;
        base = 8;
    } else
    if (*p == 'h') {  // hexadecimal
        p++;
        base = 16;
    }
    return strtol(p, NULL, base);
}
```